# The returns is not conform to the method return type but it still works

Tags: swift, optional-binding, optional-chaining

The following code snippet is simplified from the [Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245) chapter of the official document.

In short, the class **Person** has an optional stored property `address` of type **Address**. By offer some/all of the property `buildingName`, `buildingNumber` and `street` the function **buildingNumber** in the **Address** type can then be called and return a computed building identifier of type optional String.

```
class Person {
    var address: Address?
}

class Address {
    var buildingName: String?
    var buildingNumber: String?
    var street: String?

    func buildingIdentifier() -> String? {
        if buildingNumber != nil && street != nil {
            return "\(buildingNumber) \(street)" //return type is String? String?
        } else if buildingName != nil {
            return buildingName
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let john = Person()
john.address = Address()

let theAddress = Address()
theAddress.buildingNumber = "A12"
theAddress.street = "Sunset Street"
john.address = theAddress

if let johnAddressID = john.address?.buildingIdentifier() {
    print("\(johnAddressID)") //##
}
```

Let's focus on the line `return "\(buildingNumber) \(street)"` in the function **buildingIdentifier()**.

**Question1**:

The return type of the function is a optional String, however the returns whiting the functional body is 2 optional String, why this is allowed? (please see the figure below which is the printing result of the line marked by ## in the code above)

[image]

**Question 2**:

I've used the optional binding expressing (**if let**), and the binging seems sucess, but why the johnAddressID is not unwrapped then?

Thanks for stop by and help

Comment: As of Swift 3, an implicitly unwrapped optional  is treated like a regular optional in most situations, e.g in string interpolation. – Apple should updated the sample code accordingly.

Comment: In your case, `"\(buildingNumber) \(street)"` is a *regular* string with the contents `Optional("A12") Optional("Sunset Street")`